# How many ways can we make a 3-senator community where no 2 of the members are from the same state?

Tags: combinatorics

Part (a): There are $2$ senators from each of the $50$ states.

We wish to make a $3$-senator committee in which no two of the members are from the same state. In how many ways can we do it?

Part (b): Suppose for this problem (though it may not be accurate in real life) that the Senate has $47$ Republicans and $53$ Democrats. In how many ways can we form a $3$-senator committee in which neither party holds all $3$ seats?

For part (a), I got $100*98*96$ because for the first spot, there are 100 choices and person in the second spot cannot be from the same state so there are 98 choices and for the third spot there are 96. I'm not sure if this is right or not and I do not know how to do part (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (a) you’ve counted each committee $6$ times, once for each of the $6$ possible orders in which you could have picked it: ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, and CBA. As a check we can calculate it a bit differently: there are $\binom{50}3$ ways to pick the $3$ states from which the chosen senators come, and for each state we have a choice of $2$ senators, so there are $\binom{50}32^3$ ways to choose the committee. And indeed

$$\binom{50}32^3=\frac{50!2^3}{3!47!}=\frac{50\cdot49\cdot48\cdot2^3}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=\frac{100\cdot98\cdot96}6\;.$$

HINT for (b): First calculate the total number of possible $3$-person committees, and then subtract the number in which all $3$ senators are Republicans or all $3$ senators are Democrats. It’s also feasible to calculate directly the number of committees with $2$ Republicans and $1$ Democrat and the number with $2$ Democrats and $1$ Republican and add these two figures.

Comment: For part (b) would it be (100*100*47)/6 + (100*100*53)/6 ?

Comment: @3bds: (Sorry not to get back to this sooner.) No, there are $2\cdot47=94$ Republican senators and $2\cdot53=106$ Democratic ones, so there are $\binom{94}2$ ways to choose $2$ Republicans and $\binom{106}2$ ways to choose $2$ Democrats. Thus, there are $53\binom{94}2$ ways to choose $1$ Democrat and $2$ Republicans, and $47\binom{106}2$ ways to choose $1$ Republican and $2$ Democrats.

Comment: Why you closed my question while it's not duplicate?